# Doctrine: reset foreign entity before flush on the main entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

my question is simple: I'll do an update of an entity but first I need to reset foreign entity because that only can have one parent (preassigned to another entity). I'm trying on `prePersist` (and `preUpdate`) methods but I can’t save the changes from the parent class

I haven't access to `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` from the class to update previous changes.

Any idea? Many thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem comes when I have the parent entity and it have a children entity that need be updated before update the parent. I read a lot of solution but it came when I was creating the form to submit when a **createbuilder** and need to put the field that represent the children entity must **NOT** be mapped :-S

```
    $builder
    ->add('responsible', 'entity', array(
            'label' => $this->translator->trans('section.responsible'),
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => false,         // Multiple selection allowed
            'expanded' => false,        // Render as checkboxes
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Responsibles',
            'property' => 'fullName',
            'mapped' => false,
            'empty_value' => $this->translator->trans('field.select_choice'),
            'query_builder' => function (Repository $er) use ($nidOrg) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->where('a.organization = :orgNid')
                    ->setParameter('orgNid', $nidOrg);
            }))
```